# ios programmatically redraw nested views tiled

Tags: ios

I'm in the market for a nice thorough example/tutorial link or demo on programmatically creating and redrawing/resizing on rotation a view with nested tiled views. This means that the root view will need to rotate on rotation, and trigger all nested views to also rotate and resize.

For example, lets say you have a view with forty rectangle views tiled within, Id like to rotate an iphone/ipad and have the forty nested views also rotate (not hard) but more importantly resize and move. A four by ten grid might change to be five by eight.

I'm able to effect this programmatically but I'm finding that the x/y bounds etc are all off kilter.

Please no comments about "But just use storyboards"...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that it can often be a bit of effort to get it working as you'd like/expect. Things to take into consideration are the callback you are using to pick up rotation, there are 3 and they serve a slightly different purpose

`- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration`

This is probably the one you want to use, at this point when you query `self.view.frame` (or whatever you use to get the super frame) it will return the value that the frame *will* be once the rotation has complete. It also takes into account auto-resizing, and it gives you this *before* the rotation has taken place (ie no visible effect yet). Use this to calculate all the new positions and sizes of the views and set them.

`- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration`

This tells you the rotation is about to happen, but still returns the frame for the current orientation, useful for hiding/showing views, but not for calculating new positions!

`- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation`

This is called once rotation is complete, it returns the new sizes and frames, but if you attempt to reposition views here they will look as though they are jumping around after the rotation is complete.

I'd also recommend playing about with auto-resizing, as this can be a real bitch. I sometimes set the auto-resizing in code as well as in a xib juts to be sure there is no funny business!

If the rectangles are nested in a view controller they should rotate automatically (you probably knew that just thought I add it in case)

Comment: Awesome thank you. I was starting to get right off track. Part of the problem I found was having a build target of ios 6 which wasn't firing all my methods due to deprecation.